# Subversion: For merging, how to add renaming meta information later, after the commit?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution, tree-conflict

*Note: The underlying situation of this question is also part of [a slightly different question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422582/subversion-can-i-tell-the-conflict-resover-to-look-for-structural-changes-not).*

## Situation

I have a trunk, where earlier, a branch has been made from. Then, *in the trunk* some file renamings have been made. These renamings were accidentially made by "copy/delete", not with the proper svn rename process as they should have. [This is described in the TSVN docs, and in my case the "Repair move" was omitted.](https://tortoisesvn.net/repairmoves.html)

Now I have tree conflicts, when merging the branch back to the trunk:

- the merging tool does not recognise these renamings, and reports them as tree conflict
- While the "New interactive conflict resolver" should find such faulty renames, it seems to do so only on *incoming* changes, not for those in the target (trunk in my case).

## Question

- Can I, **after the fact, add meta-information about these "copy/delete" renamings**, so that Subversion now would recognise them as such?

Comment: "> While the "New interactive conflict resolver" should find such faulty renames" - no, it have not and can not. It's your task and handwork