# Subversion: Can I tell the conflict resolver, to look for structural changes not on the incomig, but on the local files?

Tags: svn, merge, file-rename, resolver, tree-conflict

*Note: The underlying situation of this question is also part of [a slightly different question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422537/subversion-for-merging-how-to-add-renaming-meta-information-later-after-the-c).*

## Situation

I have a trunk, where earlier, a branch has been made from. Then, *in the trunk* some file renamings have been made. These renamings were accidentially made by "copy/delete", not with the proper svn rename process as they should have. [This is described in the TSVN docs, and in my case the "Repair move" was omitted.](https://tortoisesvn.net/repairmoves.html)

Now I have tree conflicts, when merging the branch back to the trunk:

- the merging tool does not recognise these renamings, and reports them as tree conflict
- While the "[New interactive conflict resolver](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.10.html#conflict-resolver)" should find such faulty renames, it seems to do so only on *incoming* changes, not for those in the target (trunk in my case).

## Question

- Can I tell the **conflict resolver to look for structural changes in the *target* (local files)**, not the *incoming* tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I tell the conflict resolver to look for structural changes in the target (local files), not the incoming tree?

Yes, you can. More precisely - new resolver **do it** "automagically": see the last string of table in referenced by you chapter for "Local change - delete, incoming - edit"

Your common (here and in linked question) problem - missing rename-information, which you have to resolve (some handwork needed): you have to export dump of bad-delete changeset, fix it, import back. I done these tricks long time ago, thus - now I have only *ideas* of "How To"